# Please help on trig question: finding terminal points of angles $a$ and $b$

Tags: trigonometry

Please look at the picture below. The answer that I entered was $c_1=4/5, c_2=3/5, d_1=3/5$, and $d_2=4/5$. I came up with the conclusion when I drew a right triangle with a hypotenuse of $1$ (unit circle) and a leg with $3/5$, and another right triangle with a hypotenuse of $1$ and a leg with $4/5$. I solved for the missing sides (the cosines). My answer isn't correct, so may someone explain what I've done wrong? Thanks[image]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

From the graph, we see that angle $b$ is betwen $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, so the terminal point for $b$ is in the *second* quadrant of the unit circle. This means that $d_1$ should be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the trigonometric circle. You know that $\sin b=4/5$ (which equals $d_2$) and that $b$ is an angle between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$. What is $\cos b$ (equalling $d_1$) then?

Answer (score 0):

The terminal side of an angle $\theta$ whose vertex is at the origin and whose initial side lies along the positive x-axis intersects the unit circle intersects the unit circle at the point $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$.

[image: unit_circle_definition_of_sine_and_cosine]

This is the definition you should be using.  It does not suffice to simply draw a right triangle.  You must also take the signs of the coordinates into account.

Since $0 < a < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, the terminal side of angle $a$ lies in the first quadrant.

[image: first-quadrant_angle]

Therefore, $(c_1, c_2) = (\cos a, \sin a)$.  The sine graph that you were given shows that $\sin a = 3/5$.  By the Pythagorean Theorem,
\begin{align*}
|\cos a|^2 + |\sin a|^2 & = 1\\
|\cos a|^2 & = 1 - |\sin a|^2\\
|\cos a|^2 & = 1 - \left|\frac{3}{5}\right|^2\\
|\cos a|^2 & = 1 - \frac{9}{25}\\
|\cos a|^2 & = \frac{16}{25}\\
|\cos a| & = \frac{4}{5}
\end{align*}
Since the terminal side of angle $a$ lies in the first quadrant, $c_1 = \cos a > 0$.  Hence,
$$c_1 = \cos a = \frac{4}{5}$$
as you found since the unit circle definition agrees with the trigonometric ratio definition *if the terminal side of the angle lies in the first quadrant*.  When that is not the case, using the right triangle definition will not work.

Since $\dfrac{\pi}{2} < b < \pi$, the terminal side of angle $b$ lies in the second quadrant.

[image: second-quadrant_angle]

Therefore, $(d_1, d_2) = (\cos b, \sin b)$.  The sine graph that you were given shows that $\sin b = 4/5$.  By the Pythagorean Theorem,
\begin{align*}
|\cos b|^2 + |\sin b|^2 & = 1\\
|\cos b|^2 & = 1 - |\sin b|^2\\
|\cos b|^2 & = 1 - \left|\frac{4}{5}\right|^2\\
|\cos b|^2 & = 1 - \frac{16}{25}\\
|\cos b|^2 & = \frac{9}{25}\\
|\cos b| & = \frac{3}{5}
\end{align*}
Since the terminal side of angle $b$ lies in the second quadrant, $d_1 = \cos b < 0$.  Hence,
$$d_1 = \cos b = -\frac{3}{5}$$